# Traversing a graph (with possible loops) and returning the path in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, transitive-closure

I'm given a list of arcs:

```
arc(a,b).
arc(b,c).
arc(c,d).
arc(d,b).
arc(d,e).
arc(e,e).
arc(e,f).
```

I've written a set of clauses which will tell me if there's a path from node `X` to node `Y`.  Loops may occur and I've accounted for that.

```
path(X,Y) :-
    arc(X,Y).
path(X,Y) :-
    arc(X,Z),
    path(Z,Y,[X]).

path(X,Y,P) :-
    arc(X,Y).
path(X,Y,P) :-
    \+ member(X,P),
    arc(X,Z),
    append([X],P,L),
    path(Z,Y,L).
```

I need to modify this to, on success, return a list of nodes that were traversed.  I'm unclear as to how I would do this.

I assume my base case would be something like `path2(X,Y,[X,Y]) :- arc(X,Y).` but that won't work with my program.  Is there something wrong with my solution for the previous part, or am I just missing a small modification?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with "path(X,Y,P) :- arc(X,Y)."? (It's a good idea to make sure that all the variables in the head also exist in the body.)

Comment: It's the base case.  Once we have an arc from the current node (X) to the final node (Y) then we've found a path.  P is the list of nodes we've already visited.  I understand what you're saying and agree that P doesn't really have a use in that clause (or does it?) but I just don't see where to go from there.

Comment: Another thing: append([X],P,L) == L = [X | P]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close... but consider:

```
path(Start, End, Path) :-
    path(Start, End, [], Path).
```

Calling `path/3` with a start and end node will construct the path between them, if it exists, and backtrack to give you alternate routes. No nodes are visited twice. The `[]` is a node *accumulator* list so we can check we're not going in circles as the path is built.

```
path(Now, End, Acc, Path) :-
    arc(Now, Mid),
    Mid == End, !,
    append(Acc, [Now, End], Path).

path(Now, End, Acc, Path) :-
    arc(Now, Mid),
    \+ member(Mid, Acc),
    path(Mid, End, [Now|Acc], Path).
```

These predicates do the actual work. The first one is the base-case, where the end node is reached via another call to `arc/2`; in this case, a path has been built. The second one traverses the (directed) graph, but only to nodes that haven't been visited yet.

All paths can be located at once using `findall/3` via:

```
findall(Path, path(Start,End,Path), Paths).
```

For bound values of `Start` and `End` to node atoms.

Answer (score 1):

Move to a [higher level](http://prolog-heritage.org/en/ph4.html) and use [transitive-closure](/questions/tagged/transitive-closure)<sup>1</sup> as the basic idiom!

```
%        your binary predicate arc/2 gets used here
%         |
%         v
?- path(arc, Path, From, To).
   From = To       , Path = [To]
;  From = a, To = b, Path = [a,b] 
;  From = a, To = c, Path = [a,b,c]
;  From = a, To = d, Path = [a,b,c,d]
;  From = a, To = e, Path = [a,b,c,d,e]
;  From = a, To = f, Path = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
;  From = b, To = c, Path = [b,c]
;  From = b, To = d, Path = [b,c,d]
;  From = b, To = e, Path = [b,c,d,e]
;  From = b, To = f, Path = [b,c,d,e,f]
;  From = c, To = d, Path = [c,d]
;  From = c, To = b, Path = [c,d,b]
;  From = c, To = e, Path = [c,d,e]
;  From = c, To = f, Path = [c,d,e,f]
;  From = d, To = b, Path = [d,b]
;  From = d, To = c, Path = [d,b,c]
;  From = d, To = e, Path = [d,e]
;  From = d, To = f, Path = [d,e,f]
;  From = e, To = f, Path = [e,f]
;  false.
```

---

<sup>**Footnote 1:** As implemented by the versatile [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`path/4`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30328433/4609915).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by sharky doesn't seem to work for me, but the following mod does and feels more straightforward to me. :

```
path(Now, End, Acc, [Now,End]) :-
    arc(Now, End),
    \+ member(Now, Acc),
    \+ member(End, Acc).

path(Now, End, Acc, Path) :-
    arc(Now, Mid),
    \+ member(Mid, Acc),
    path(Mid, End, [Now|Acc], Path).
```

Do tell me if I'm missing something.