# Prolog pathloop fail

Tags: prolog, graph-theory

I have this program:

```
region(r1, 2110, [1,2]).
region(r2, 2210, [4,5,8]).
region(r3, 2310, [3,6]).
region(r4, 2410, [7,10,11,15]).
region(r5, 2510, [9,12]).
region(r6, 2610, [13,14]).

telephone(2310-6-64221, name(asd, nikos)).
telephone(2510-12-24234, name(dsa, kiki)).

next_to(2, 1).
next_to(1,4).
next_to(4, 5).
next_to(4, 8).
next_to(3, 6).
next_to(3, 5).
next_to(5, 8).
next_to(8, 9).
next_to(6, 7).
next_to(7, 10).
next_to(9, 12).
next_to(10, 11).
next_to(10, 15).
next_to(12, 15).
next_to(13, 14).

connect(X, Y) :-
    next_to(X, Y).
connect(X, Y) :-
    next_to(Y, X).

pathloop(Start, End, _, Path) :-
    connect(Start, End),
    Path = [Start, End].
pathloop(Start, End, Visited, Path) :-
    connect(Start, Middle),
    not(member(Middle, Visited)),
    pathloop(Middle, End, [Middle|Visited], PathRest),
    Path = [Start|PathRest].

can_call(PersonA, PersonB, Route) :-
    telephone(_-Area1-_, name(PersonA, _)),
    telephone(_-Area2-_, name(PersonB, _)),
    pathloop(Area1, Area2,_, Route).
```

Everything runs except `pathloop` the base runs but the recursive one must to display a list `Path` which contains a path from A to B. But when i run the program and i type `?- can_call(asd, dsa, Route)`,
it fails (returns `false`.). What I have to change on `pathloop`? i tried 
`?- pathloop(1, 5, [], Path).` and it shows 10-20 results and then `false`.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried `?- pathloop(1,5,[],Path).` and it shows 10-20 results and then `false`.

Let's look at the answers in detail and highlight any spurious parts...

```
?- pathloop(1,5,[],Path).
  Path = [1,4,5]                                       % ok
; Path = [1,4,5,8,5]
; Path = [1,4,5,8,9,12,15,10,7,6,3,5]
; Path = [1,4,5,3,5]
; Path = [1,4,5,3,6,7,10,15,12,9,8,5]
; Path = [1,4,8,5]                                     % ok
; Path = [1,4,8,9,12,15,10,7,6,3,5]                    % ok
; Path = [1,4,8,5,3,5]
; Path = [1,2,1,4,5]
; Path = [1,2,1,4,5,8,5]
; Path = [1,2,1,4,5,8,9,12,15,10,7,6,3,5]
; Path = [1,2,1,4,5,3,5]
; Path = [1,2,1,4,5,3,6,7,10,15,12,9,8,5]
; Path = [1,2,1,4,8,5]
; Path = [1,2,1,4,8,9,12,15,10,7,6,3,5]
; Path = [1,2,1,4,8,5,3,5]
; false.
```

Current status: **17 out of 20 answers are invalid!**

To fix this we use [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`path/4`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328433/definition-of-a-path-trail-walk):

```
?- path(connect,Path,1,5).
  Path = [1,4,5]
; Path = [1,4,8,9,12,15,10,7,6,3,5]
; Path = [1,4,8,5]
; false.
```

**Ok!** Next, we adapt the definition of `can_call/3` to use `path/4` instead of `pathloop/4`:

```
can_call(PersonA, PersonB, Route) :-
    telephone(_-Area1-_, name(PersonA, _)),
    telephone(_-Area2-_, name(PersonB, _)),
    path(connect,Route,Area1,Area2).
```

> But when I run [...] `?- can_call(asd,dsa,Route).`, it fails (returns `false`.)

Let's re-run above query with the new version of `can_call/3`!

```
?- can_call(asd,dsa,Route).
  Route = [6,7,10,15,12]
; Route = [6,3, 5, 8, 9,12]
; Route = [6,3, 5, 4, 8, 9,12]
; false.
```

It works!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you make the call to `pathloop/4` in `can_call/3`, you pass an ungrounded variable `_` to `Visited`. In other words, you give an uninstantiated list. Now if you do a member check `member(a,X)` with `X` thus uninstantiated, it will say, "*Yes! that's possible, simply make `X=[a|_]`*".

So in order to fix this, rewrite `can_call/3` to:

```
can_call(PersonA, PersonB, Route) :-
    telephone(_-Area1-_, name(PersonA, _)),
    telephone(_-Area2-_, name(PersonB, _)),
    pathloop(Area1, Area2,[Area1], Route).
```

Since at that moment, you have only visited Area1.

## Additional advice

I think it makes more sense that the base case is defined as arriving at the destination:

```
pathloop(End,End, _,[End]) :-
    !.
```

The "*cut*" (`!`) disables the fact that once you reached the destination, you will keep searching for loops. For instance if you want to connect from `4` to `5`. It will not propose a route like `4 -> 5 -> 8 -> 4 -> 5` thus looping after reaching.

Next the inductive case searches for a `Next` (I would not call it a `Middle` because it is not the node in the middle, but one that is next to the start.

```
pathloop(Start, End, Visited,[Start|Path]) :-
    connect(Start, Middle),
    \+ member(Middle, Visited),
    pathloop(Middle, End,[Middle|Visited],Path).
```

It is also better not to use unifications `X=[A|B]`, if these can already be made at the head level. It allows faster execution, especially if you would call the predicate in the opposite direction.

Comment: Thank you i just put cut (!) on the end of base and the recursion and it works

Comment: You don't have to put a cut on the end of the recursion. A cut means you don't consider any of the following clauses of that predicate. In other words, if Prolog reaches `!` in the base case. It will not invest effort in calling the recursive case as well. There is however no alternative after the recursive case. There is no disadvantage, but it is useless statement.

Comment: Beware that using `(!)/0` breaks steadfastness of your code.