# Writing a Prolog predicate to supply default parameters to another predicate

Tags: prolog, optional-parameters, default-parameters

I'm learning Prolog and I followed
[this tutorial for graphs](http://rlgomes.github.io/work/prolog/2012/05/22/19.00-prolog-and-graphs.html).
Here's my code:

```
path(X, Y, Length, [X,Y], _) :- 
   connect(X, Y, Length).   
path(X, Y, Length, [X|P], V) :- 
   \+ member(X, V),
   connect(X, Z, Length1),
   path(Z, Y, Length2, P, [X|V]),
   Length is Length1 + Length2.
```

To use this, I call

```
?- path(a, f, Length, Path, []).
```

However, I would like to shorten it to:

```
?- path(a, f, Length, Path).
```

But I can't get the default parameters to work.

Comment: See [`this definition`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30328433).

Comment: @false I did initially link this very question; however, if the edges have values associated with them, it is only half the answer. I want to use this opportunity to ask: is there a single place where one can find all the great code written by you (and some of the great answers)? Currently it is scattered around the Prolog tag, and I often have trouble finding it even though I know it is somewhere out there...

Comment: @Boris: See my profile and [this place](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/). I plan to put them into a more comprehensive form, but it is much more work than it seems for I try to be conforming in *all* possible respects.

Comment: @false Yes, I usually find it by looking at your profile. I realize it is a daunting job, but if you have a website anyway even just dumping a working version of each individual solution with a descriptive name would make it easier to browse and search. I guess doing it properly is about the same as writing a textbook.

Comment: @Boris: Ideally, the SO answers should be readily available...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quite straight-forward: just define a predicate with the same name that calls the predicate doing the work:

```
path(X, Y, Length, Path) :-
    path(X, Y, Length, Path, []).
```

In Prolog, predicates are always referred to with `Name/Arity` because same name but different arity makes them two separate predicates. So, now your program will have both `path/4` and `path/5` defined.

As to naming: if both predicates are part of your interface, they should have the same name. Many examples in Prolog standard libraries, for example [`format/1`, `format/2`, `format/3`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=format-predicates).

If, however, the working predicate is only meant to be used as a helper predicate, usually you give it a suffix. To use something simple as `list_max/2`:

```
list_max([X|Xs], Max) :-
    list_max_SUFFIX(Xs, X, Max).
```

I have seen code where `SUFFIX` is just an underscore: `list_max_/3` (and you keep adding underscores for more helper predicates down the same predicate lineage); or, underscore + number: `list_max_1/3` (and you increment the number); or, `_aux` + optional number, if you have more: `list_max_aux/3`. Using the underscore + number:

```
list_max_1([], Max, Max).
list_max_1([X|Xs], Max0, Max) :-
    compare(Order, X, Max0),
    list_max_2(Order, X, Max0, Xs, Max).

list_max_2(<, _, Max0, Xs, Max) :- list_max_1(Xs, Max0, Max).
list_max_2(=, _, Max0, Xs, Max) :- list_max_1(Xs, Max0, Max).
list_max_2(>, X, _, Xs, Max) :- list_max_1(Xs, X, Max).
```

But wait, there's more. If you use a naming scheme for your predicates where the name represents the arguments, you get for example [`setup_call_cleanup/3`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=setup_call_cleanup/3), and [`call_cleanup/2`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=call_cleanup/2), defined as `setup_call_cleanup(true, Goal, Cleanup)`. With this naming scheme, you would call your "path" predicates maybe `from_to_length_path/4` and `from_to_length_path_acc/5`. I find this naming scheme nice because it is self-documenting, but as this example shows, it could become excessive if your predicate has too many arguments.

Comment: s(X) for your elaborate answer!

Comment: @repeat Apparently, I've got nothing better to do and nowhere else to be.

Comment: There **is** nothing better to do and nowhere else to be:)