# How can I return a list of edges in a graph from one node to another?

Tags: algorithm, prolog, graph-theory

Here's the question I'm trying to solve:

> Write and test the clauses for the relation:
>   listForPath(X,Y,L) %the path between X and Y is the list L.

Here are the graphs we're working with:

```
edge(a,b,2).
edge(b,c,2).
edge(c,d,2).
edge(d,a,2).
```

as well as

```
edge(a, c, 2). 
edge(b, e, 2).
edge(d, e, 1).
edge(c, d, 2).
edge(a, b, 2). 
edge(a, d, 3).
edge(b, a, 1).
edge(a, a, 2).
```

our expected output is as follows:

```
?- listForPath(a,d,L).

L = [edge(a,b,2),edge(b,c,2),edge(c,d,2)] ;
L = [edge(a,b,2),edge(b,c,2),edge(c,d,2),edge(d,a,2),edge(a,b,2),edge(b,c,2),edge(c,d,2)] ;
```

I've been playing around with this for a while and here's what I have:

```
listForPath(X,Y,L):-
  edge(X,Y,Z),
  L=[edge(X,Y,Z)].

listForPath(X,Y,L):-
  edge(X,Z,W),
  listForPath(Z,Y,L2),
  append([edge(X,Z,W)],L2,L).
```

From this, I'm getting this output:

```
89 ?- listForPath(a,d,L).
L = [edge(a, d, 3)] ;
L = [edge(a, b, 2), edge(b, c, 2), edge(c, d, 2)] ;
L = [edge(a, b, 2), edge(b, c, 2), edge(c, d, 2)] ;
L = [edge(a, b, 2), edge(b, c, 2), edge(c, d, 2), edge(d, a, 2), edge(a, d, 3)] ;
L = [edge(a, b, 2), edge(b, c, 2), edge(c, d, 2), edge(d, a, 2), edge(a, b, 2), edge(b, c, 2), edge(c, d, 2)] ;
L = [edge(a, b, 2), edge(b, c, 2), edge(c, d, 2), edge(d, a, 2), edge(a, b, 2), edge(b, c, 2), edge(c, d, 2)] ;
L = [edge(a, b, 2), edge(b, c, 2), edge(c, d, 2), edge(d, a, 2), edge(a, b, 2), edge(b, c, 2), edge(c, d, 2), edge(d, a, 2), edge(..., ..., ...)] .
```

So, I think I'm close as I'm getting the something that resembles the desired output, but it appears as though I'm getting stuck in the loop and I can't get out! Can anyone help. Please?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30328433/772868).

Comment: I'm not seeing how I can use that to modify my code and make it work the way it should.