# DAG Traversal + Cost in Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, graph-traversal

I'm trying to implement a DAG traversal algorithm that also gets the costs between the edges. I think I'm pretty close but queries always return paths that aren't valid. Can anyone take a look and see what I'm missing here?

```
edge(b, a, 5).
edge(a, u, 10).
edge(u, o, 140).
edge(u, r, 130).
edge(r, o, 20).
edge(r, v, 50).
edge(o, v, 45).
edge(b, v, 20).

path(Start, Start, [], 0).
path(Start, Finish, [Start, Finish], C) :-
    edge(Start, Finish, Cost),
    C is Cost.
path(Start, Finish, [Start|Path], C) :-
    edge(Start, X, Cost),
    path(X, Finish, Path, RCost),
    C is Cost + RCost.
```

I'm trying to run `path(b, v, S, C).`. It is generating all the valid paths, but it's also generating a few invalid paths.

```
C = 20,
S = [b, v]
C = 200,
S = [b, a, u, o, v]
C = 200,
S = [b, a, u, o]
C = 195,
S = [b, a, u, r, v]
C = 210,
S = [b, a, u, r, o, v]
C = 210,
S = [b, a, u, r, o]
C = 195,
S = [b, a, u, r]
C = 20,
S = [b]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The best graph traversal code I have seen is in this question: 
[Definition of a path/trail/walk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328433/definition-of-a-path-trail-walk/30595271#30595271)

We can adapt that for your case to be:

```
edge(b, a, 5).
edge(a, u, 10).
edge(u, o, 140).
edge(u, r, 130).
edge(r, o, 20).
edge(r, v, 50).
edge(o, v, 45).
edge(b, v, 20).


:- meta_predicate path(3,?,?,?).

:- meta_predicate path(3,?,?,?,+).

path(R_3, [X0|Ys], X0,X) :-
   path(R_3, Ys, X0,X, [X0]).

path(_R_3, [], X-0,X-0, _).
path(R_3, [X1-Cost2|Ys], X0-Cost,X, Xs) :-
   call(R_3, X0,X1,Cost),
   non_member(X1, Xs),
   path(R_3, Ys, X1-Cost2,X, [X1-Cost2|Xs]).

non_member(_E, []).
non_member(E, [X-_Cost|Xs]) :-
   dif(E,X),
   non_member(E, Xs).
```

Then we can query :

```
?- path(edge,Path,From,To).
Path = [_22918-0],
From = To, To = _22918-0 ;
Path = [b-5, a-0],
From = b-5,
To = a-0 ;
Path = [b-5, a-10, u-0],
From = b-5,
To = u-0 ;
Path = [b-5, a-10, u-140, o-0],
From = b-5,
To = o-0 ;
Path = [b-5, a-10, u-140, o-45, v-0],
From = b-5,
To = v-0 ;
```

etc

So we get a list of nodes with the cost to get to the next node.
You can then simply sum them like this:

```
?- path(edge,Path,From,To), pairs_values(Path,Values), sumlist(Values,Sum).
Path = [_24478-0],
From = To, To = _24478-0,
Values = [0],
Sum = 0 ;
Path = [b-5, a-0],
From = b-5,
To = a-0,
Values = [5, 0],
Sum = 5 ;
Path = [b-5, a-10, u-0],
From = b-5,
To = u-0,
Values = [5, 10, 0],
Sum = 15 ;
Path = [b-5, a-10, u-140, o-0],
From = b-5,
To = o-0,
Values = [5, 10, 140, 0],
Sum = 155
```

etc

or you could adapt the code to count the sum as you go saving sum computation.

In this I think we are assuming that there is only one edge from any one node to another.

Answer (score 1):

You have one error in your code. This:

```
path(Start, Start, [], 0).
```

should have been

```
path(Start, Start, [Start], 0).
```

otherwise `Path` in

```
path(Start, Finish, [Start|Path], C) :-
    edge(Start, X, Cost),
    path(X, Finish, Path, RCost),
    C is Cost + RCost.
```

comes back empty from that (first) clause, but what you really intended here is for it to contain `Finish` as the last element.

Indeed this follows from the logical reading of your predicate as well. If `path(Start, Start, Path, Cost)` is to succeed, it means there's a `Path` from `Start` to `Start`, which *is* the non-empty `[Start]`. An empty path is no path at all.

Now all reported paths are valid. Some are reported multiple times, but that's another issue.