# How to answer this prolog question about paths?

Tags: prolog

https://i.ibb.co/q0zXPGv/qe.jpg

In Prolog, we can introduce a predicate about edge direction to represent the above graph:

```
edge(s,a).
edge(a,b).
```

We further introduce a predicate about node connectivity:

```
connected(X,Y) :- edge(X,Y).
connected(X,Y) :- edge(X,Z), connected(Z,Y).
```

Now, we would like to further extend our program with a predicate `path(X,Y,P)`which will use variable `P` to hold a list of nodes which constitute a valid path from node `X` to node `Y`.

Implement the path predicate and write the answer of the Prolog system to the following queries:
1.  ?- path(s,f,P).
2.  ?- path(d,c,P).
3.  ?- path(s,g,P).
4.  ?- path(s,e,P).
[Image of path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/en07v.jpg)

Comment: See [`path/4`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30328433/772868) for a generic solution that even works with cyclic graphs.

Answer (score 1):

Let's check my solution to the problem:

```
edge(s,a).
edge(s,f).
edge(s,e).
edge(f,e).
edge(a,b).
edge(e,d).
edge(d,a).
edge(d,c).
edge(b,c).
edge(c,g).

connected(X,Y):- edge(X,Y).
connected(X,Y):- edge(X,Z), connected(Z,Y).

path(X,X,[X]).
path(X,Y,[X|P]):- connected(X,Z), path(Z,Y,P),!.
```

If the path is from the node to the node itself then the result must be the node.
Otherwise, node X should be in the path if we can go from X to Y through some node(s) Z.

I don't really like the implementation of connected because it forces you tou cut the solution.

Hope it helps! Here are the answers to the queries above:

```
?- path(s,f,P).
P = [s, f].

?- path(d,c,P).
P = [d, a, b, c].

?- path(s,g,P).
P = [s, a, b, c, g].

?- path(s,e,P).
P = [s, f, e].
```