# How do I find all the paths with prolog?

Tags: prolog

```
start(b1).
end(b6).

edge(b1,b2).
edge(b1,b6).
edge(b2,b3).
edge(b2,b4).
edge(b3,b5).
edge(b4,b5).
edge(b5,b1).

constraint(b5,2).
```

Task:
The predicate path (X, Y, V, P) is now used to determine paths that go from a node X to Y. Cycles should not be avoided entirely - instead, loop loops should be used
constraint (K, N) each node K only appear at most N times in the path, if this is restricted accordingly. The determined paths should be complete and in the correct order. To simplify matters, it can be assumed that X is always a start node and Y is an end node.
Example query / output:

```
?- path(b1,b6,[],P).
P = [b1, b6] ;
P = [b1, b2, b3, b5, b1, b6] ;
P = [b1, b2, b3, b5, b1, b2, b3, b5, b1|...] ;
P = [b1, b2, b3, b5, b1, b2, b4, b5, b1|...] ;
P = [b1, b2, b4, b5, b1, b6]
....
```

My hopeless  attempt :

```
path(X,Y,[H|T],P) :-
   edge(X,Z), count(Z,[H|T],M), constraint(M,2), path(Z,Y,[X|T],P).
```

I believe that I am on the right way, but I have no base case.

Hope someone knows the way to go?

Comment: Where does this loop constraint come from?

Comment: Should you decide to opt for an acyclic path, use: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30328433/772868). You miight take this as a starting point and insert cycles thereafter