# Path search in a tree from generic start and end nodes using prolog

Tags: prolog

I am searching for paths using some generic definitions. For example, when I search for `A` to `B`, I actually want to find paths like `A` to `B`, `A_1` to `B_2`, `A` to `B_1`, or `A_5` to `B`.

The middle nodes traversed may or may not be have a suffix like _N based on the connections in the tree.
My prolog statement is like below.

```
path(A,B,Path) :-
  travel(A,B,[A],Q),
  reverse(Q,Path).

travel(A,B,P,[B|P]) :-
  arc(A,B).
travel(A,B,Visited,Path) :-
  arc(A,C),
  C \== B,
  \+member(C,Visited),
  travel(C,B,[C|Visited],Path).
```

Using this prolog code, I can find some paths but can not find others. For example, for the generic search criteria A -->15

> Paths like (A, 1, 4, 7, 15) are ok,
>
> Paths like (A, 1_1, 4_3, 7, 15) are also ok
>
> Paths like
>
> - (A_1, X, X, X, 15)
> - (A, X, X, X, 15_2),
> - (A_3, X, X, X, 15_1)
>
> are not ok

Note: X is a placeholder for any node either with the underscore or not.

Can you please help me to find out the problem.

Many thanks,
Ferda

Comment: Consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30328433/772868).

Comment: Which part do you recommend? That problem looks different and there are lots of code suggestions..

Comment: `path(arc, Path, A, B)` implements your task. All what is listed there as "implementation" is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding this line solved the problem.

```
path_generic(A,B,Path) :- path(X,Y,Path),sub_atom(X,0,_,_,A), sub_atom(Y,0,_,_,B).
```

Answer (score 2):

I would extend the `arc/2` predicate, or better, would introduce a service `arc_ext/2`, and would change `travel/4` accordingly:

```
travel(A,B,P,[B|P]) :- arc_ext(A,B).
travel(A,B,Visited,Path) :- arc_ext(A,C),...

% TBD: optimize, when the logic has been tested
arc_ext(A,B) :-
  arc(X,Y),
  sub_atom(X,0,_,_,A), % X starts with A
  sub_atom(Y,0,_,_,B).
```

Comment: Hi @CapelliC, Your answer (sub_atom parts) helped me find the solution. Many thanks..