# Finding shortest path in water jugs problem

Tags: prolog, clpfd, water-jug-problem

Here's my solution for the water jugs problem

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

initial(state(8, 0, 0)).
final(state(4, 4, 0)).

constraint(A0, A1, B0, B1, C0, C1, V) :-
  A0 #< A1,
  ( B0 #> 0, T #= min(V - A0, B0), A1 #= A0 + T, B1 #= B0 - T, C1 #= C0
  ; C0 #> 0, T #= min(V - A0, C0), A1 #= A0 + T, C1 #= C0 - T, B1 #= B0
  ).

transition(state(A0, B0, C0), state(A1, B1, C1)) :-
  ( constraint(A0, A1, B0, B1, C0, C1, 8)
  ; constraint(B0, B1, A0, A1, C0, C1, 5)
  ; constraint(C0, C1, A0, A1, B0, B1, 3)
  ).

solve(A, A, _, [A]).
solve(A, B, P, [A|Q]) :-
  transition(A, A1),
  \+ member(A1, P),
  solve(A1, B, [A|P], Q).

path(P) :-
  initial(S0),
  final(S),
  solve(S0, S, [], P).
```

Is there a way to find the `P` of minimal length without traversing all options?

Comment: Consider [`path(transitition, P, S0, S)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30328433/772868) in stead.

Comment: `?- length(P, N), path(P).` finds the shortest solution first.

Comment: `length(P, N)` is a cool trick, but must be super inefficient?

Comment: In the context of general (uninformed) search problems, iterative deepening is not that bad.

Comment: OTOH, it is *extremely inefficient* in case there is no solution. In fact, it loops instead of finite failure. So if you want to avoid this, first ensure that there is *some* path.

Comment: As exercise (not as answer) I coded this problem in MiniZinc: [gist](https://gist.github.com/dtonhofer/22566f98671f3fbdb3e4dad554841171). The problem as stated apparently has no solution. I try to minimize the number of operations. Depending on the solver actually used, one may find longer or shorter "paths" rapidly.

Comment: A complete rework of [MiniZinc code](https://gist.github.com/dtonhofer/22566f98671f3fbdb3e4dad554841171) has been performed. It now actually works properly. Developing the right constraints is an art 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that makes more use of the power of clpfd: First state the problem, then try to solve it (using `labeling/2` or similar). Given that we do not know the length of the (shortest) path, this will generate larger and larger problems until a solution is found. In my code, I do not prevent visiting the same state twice (but this could be added in the same way as in the MiniZinc model written by @DavidTonhofer, or as some post-processing). However, in order to ensure a finite search space, I've added code to stop the problem generation if the length of the path is longer than `(5+1)*(3+1)`, as this is an upper bound on the number of different states (assuming we have do not add or remove water outside of the 3 jugs).

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

initial(state(8, 0, 0)).
final(state(4, 4, 0)).


constraint(A0,A1,B0,B1,C0,C1,R,Max):-
  T#=min(Max-B0,A0),
  R in 0..1,
  R#==>T#>0,
  R#==>A1#=A0-T,
  R#==>B1#=B0+T,
  R#==>C1#=C0.
  

transition(state(A0, B0, C0), state(A1, B1, C1)) :-
  A0+B0+C0#=A1+B1+C1,
  A0 in 0..8,
  B0 in 0..5,
  C0 in 0..3,
  A1 in 0..8,
  B1 in 0..5,
  C1 in 0..3,
  constraint(A0,A1,B0,B1,C0,C1,RAB,5),
  constraint(B0,B1,A0,A1,C0,C1,RBA,8),
  constraint(A0,A1,C0,C1,B0,B1,RAC,3),
  constraint(C0,C1,A0,A1,B0,B1,RCA,8),
  constraint(C0,C1,B0,B1,A0,A1,RCB,5),
  constraint(B0,B1,C0,C1,A0,A1,RBC,3),
  RAB+RBA+RAC+RCA+RCB+RBC#=1.


solve(A, A, Xs, [A]):-
  labeling([],Xs).
solve(A, B, Xs, [A|Q]) :-
  length(Xs, L),
  L < 24*3,
  transition(A, A1),
  A=state(X1,X2,X3),
  solve(A1, B, [X1,X2,X3|Xs], Q).

path(P) :-
  initial(S0),
  final(S),
  solve(S0, S, [], P).
```

I tried to keep the code relatively close to the one in the question. The main difference is that all the prolog-level disjunctions in `transition/2` and `constraint/7` have been removed and replaced by reification. In particular, I added the parameter `R` to `constraint/8` which is equal to `1` if that specific transition is taken. Then I state in `transition/2` that exactly one of the transitions must take place.

I must add that this formulation is not particularly efficient and I would not be surprised to find out that one can solve the problem more efficiently with either a different clpfd formulation or without using clpfd at all.