# Prolog seemingly ending recursive call without going back up

Tags: prolog

I've got the following two edges defined:

```
edge(a,b).
edge(b,c).

add(X, L, [X | L]).
```

Now I'm trying to recursively build the path from a to c (a,b,c) using this:

```
path(FROM,TO,W):-
    edge(FROM,TO),
    add(TO, [], X),
    add(FROM, X, W).
path(FROM,TO,W):-
    edge(FROM,Y),
    path(Y,TO, W),
    add(FROM, W, _).
```

It seems to work fine in the base case as `path(a,b,X)` will output `X = [a,b]`.
However, `path(a,c,X)` only outputs `X = [b,c]`, as if it just gets to the base case and ends it there rather than going back up the recursive call.
Ultimately, I would like it to output `X = [a,b,c]` but I'm out of ideas.

FYI I'm using SWI-Prolog.

Comment: Yes you're right, I've edited this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work correctly because it discards the result produced by the subgoal `add(FROM, W, _)`, in the second clause of the predicate `path/3`. To solve the problem, you need to modify your code as following:

```
path(From, To, W):-
    edge(From, To),
    add(To, [], X),
    add(From, X, W).

path(From, To, PATH):-   
    edge(From, Y),
    path(Y,To, W),
    add(From, W, PATH). % <== get PATH
```

An even better version of this code is as follows:

```
path(From, To, [From, To]) :-
    edge(From, To).

path(From, To, [From|Path]) :-
    edge(From, X),
    path(X, To, Path).
```

Comment: Legend, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

How can you identify the problem yourself? There is an easy way to do so. First, identify the cases you expect to be true *and* cases you expect it to fail. Here are some plus some auxiliary definitions to ease debugging

```
:- initialization(path(a,b,[a,b])).
:- initialization(path(a,c,[a,b,c])).   % intended to be true, initially false
:- initialization(\+path(a,b,[a,_,c])).
:- initialization(\+path(a,d,_)).       % no node d, thus no path

:- op(950, fy, *).
:- meta_predicate(*(0)).

*_G_0.   % this permits us to remove goals by adding a * in front.
```

Now,  save the program ..and say `[program]`. You will get a warning like

```
* user:user:path(a,c,[a,b,c]) - goal failed
```

So we know that we have not solved the problem.

Now, try to generalize the program by adding `*` in front of a goal. You will note that for each and every such generalization there will be more errors appearing (and in one case even non-termination). Except for the last goal where everything remains the same.  So removing or replacing that goal seems to be a good idea.

Sooner or later you will encounter cycles. For acyclic paths, use [`path/4`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30328433/772868):

```
?- path(edge, Path, A, B).
```