# Prevent cycle in Depth first search using prolog

Tags: prolog, artificial-intelligence, depth-first-search

Is there any way to prevent cycle in this code.

```
move(a,b).
move(b,a).
move(a,c).
move(b,d).
move(b,e).
move(d,h).
move(d,i).
move(e,j).
move(e,k).
move(c,f).
move(c,g).
move(f,l).
move(f,m).
move(g,n).
move(g,o).
goal(n).


goSolveTheMaze(Start,Way) :-
    dfs(Start, Way),!.

dfs(Goal, [Goal]) :-
   goal(Goal),!.

dfs(Start, [Start|Way])  :-
    move(Start, N),
    dfs(N, Way).
```

so when `move(a,b)` move to `(b,c)` dont go back to `(b,a)`,
when run `goSolveTheMaze(a,path)`.
The output should be `path=[a,c,g,n]`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30328433/772868

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you add a third argument to `dfs` which is a list of where you've already visited? You could then use [\+/1](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=%5C%2B/1) and [member/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=member/2) to avoid returning to places you've already been.

For example, if you use the following:

```
move(a,b).
move(b,a).
move(a,c).
move(b,d).
move(b,e).
move(d,h).
move(d,i).
move(e,j).
move(e,k).
move(c,f).
move(c,g).
move(f,l).
move(f,m).
move(g,n).
move(g,o).
goal(n).


goSolveTheMaze(Start,Way) :-
    dfs(Start, Way, [Start]),!.

dfs(Goal, [Goal], _) :-
   goal(Goal),!.

dfs(Start, [Start|Way], Visited)  :-
    move(Start, N),
    \+ member(N, Visited),
    dfs(N, Way, [N|Visited]).
```

Then the query:

```
?- goSolveTheMaze(a, X).
```

Will produce the result:

```
X = [a, c, g, n]
```

---

Update in response to comment "can you tell me what \+ do?":

The [\+](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=%5C%2B/1) predicate is true when its argument cannot be proven. Therefore in the above example the line `\+ member(N, Visited)` means "when N is *not* a member of the list Visited".

See: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=%5C%2B/1

Comment: can you tell me what  \+ do ?