# Prolog define orthogonal constaint

Tags: prolog

I am quite new in the Prolog magical universe, but it seems to be very powerful to solve my problem.

I have two basis `[i0,j0,k0]` and `[i1,j1,k1]`. Then we have an orthogonal constraint between all elements of the same basis (`i0` is orthogonal to `j0`, `j0` is orthogonal to `k0`, and `k0` is orthogonal to `i0`).

I would like to find the set of new orthogonal constraint to add between elements of the first basis and the second one such that the two basis are aligned/equal. Then it could be interesting to find the minimal number of constraints (which seems to be 3 when you think about it).

I have working a start of code (but you can give me tips and tricks to have a more efficient code) but then I'm stuck when I need to express the goal of my problem ...

Let's define define `ortho/1` such that all the elements in the list given to ortho are ortho one to another. Then we could define our two basis:

```
ortho([i0,j0,k0]).
ortho([i1,j1,k1]).
```

I add then the following rule to deduce `ortho([X,Y])` from `ortho([X,Y,Z])` predicates:

```
ortho(L) :- ortho(B), unique(L), unordered_subset(B,L).
```

This could be explained as we need to find an existing basis `B` such that `L` is a sublist of `B` and all elements of `L` are distinct. Some tests are leading to:

```
?- ortho([i0,j0]).
true.
?- ortho([k0,i0]).
true.
?- ortho([i0,i0]).
false.
```

Here is the implementation of `unique/1`, `subset/2` and `unordered_subset/2` I used in my program (Found on StackOverflow, don't know if there is better but it seems to work).

```
% unique/1 detect list formed by unique elements
unique([]).
unique([X|Xs]) :- \+ memberchk(X, Xs), unique(Xs).

% subset/2 (set, subset) true if subset is a subset of set in the same order
subset([], []).
subset([E|Tail], [E|NTail]):-
    subset(Tail, NTail).
subset([_|Tail], NTail):-
    subset(Tail, NTail).

% unordered_subset/2 (set, subset) true if subset is a subset of set
unordered_subset(Set, SubSet):-
    length(Set, LSet),
    between(0,LSet, LSubSet),
    length(NSubSet, LSubSet),
    permutation(SubSet, NSubSet),
    subset(Set, NSubSet).
```

The finality is to see if the two basis are equal. To do so, I defined `equal/2` and `collin/2` such that:

```
% collin/2 check the collinearity of two vectors
collin(A,B) :-
    ortho([X,Y,A]), ortho([X,B]), ortho([Y,B]).

% equal/2 check basis equals
equal([],[]).
equal([H1|T1],[H2|T2]) :-
    collin(H1,H2),
    equal(T1,T2).
```

`collin/2` is based on the fact that two vectors `A` and `B` are collinear if it exists `X` and `Y` such that `[X,Y,A]` is a basis and `X` and `Y` are both orthogonal to `B`. And `equal/2` is the fact that two basis are equal if the vectors taken in the good order are collinear. (By commutativity Prolog should be able to find this good order).

To find a solution to my problem, I think there is something about finding a list of pairs `T` of length `N`, with N as low as possible, such that for all pair `P=X-Y` in T, `ortho(X,Y)` implies `equal([i0,j0,k0], [i1,j1,k1])`.

Could you help me to express this rule ? (And eventually to have a better code :) )

Answer (score 0):

Your `unique/1` only works when the list has been fully populated - which violates the "fail fast" principle of performant code. Should check at the point that the individual list elements become instantiated - which can be done using `freeze`.

The most *correct* unique definition that I've seen is `all_dif` in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31724022/ (because it works when the list's tail is later extended).